# Setting Combobox.Selected programmatically, but I cannot get a selection to appear

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

So in MS Access 2010 I have a main form for viewing client details, and tabbed subform navigation with subforms showing information in different tables for said client. On one page, i have a combobox to select a date for viewing a testing session related to the client. I am trying to get the first combobox value to be selected automatically when the user goes to this tab and/or cycles through other users while viewing this tab. My simple VB code is below:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.DateOfScreening.Requery
    Me.DateOfScreening.Selected(2) = True
End Sub
```

The requery command is executing (paging through different clients will update the combobox values, and commenting that line out stops that behavior, so I know this code block is getting executed), but the Selected command appears to not select anything.

I hope I am just missing something obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, setting the selected row index for a combo box has not behaved well for me.
Could you just set the combobox value directly, as in

```
        Me.DateOfScreening = "yourValue"
```

Also, when referencing the control, you can use either

```
   me.dateofScreening.column(0)    'if 0 is your bound col index
```

or maybe

```
  me.dateofScreening.itemdata(0)
```

Also, could you do a debug.print(me.dateofScreening.column(0)) or msgbox (me.dateofScreening.column(0)) and let me know if it says anything.

Comment: msgbox returns the id of the row I'm accessing (which is what I'm storing in that combobox, so thats right)

Comment: Great, so- is this working as intended or is there something else that you need help with?

Comment: sorry about the prior comment, posted it prematurely. anyway, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I had no idea that setting the value would pick the row associated with that value. I ended up doing this: `Me.DateOfScreening.Value = Me.DateOfScreening.Column(0, 0)`

Comment: Glad you could figure out a solution. And welcome to StackOverflow